# Require Current Selected Standard or CustomObject name in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I am writing a chrome addon which will get the Current selected standard or custom object by the user and displays the information about it. I have used dom fetching method but it is not reliable.

How to accomplish this by using SOQL query or rest api call?

Answer (score 0):

Perform a rest call to:

```
 https://[instance].salesforce.com/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/
```

This would provide all the objects there are available to the current logged in user

Comment: It will show all objects but I want current object on which user is working

Comment: What do you mean by "current object on which the user is working", the current selected tab?

Comment: Yes the selected tab

Comment: I don't think there is an api for this at least not one that I am aware of.  I know they recently implemented a UI API so maybe it's worth looking at that.  I'd be interested in learning what you find. Page scraping could always be done but that's brittle and not recommended